# How can I get the values in dask series structure?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, series

I passed the data which is in excel sheet with columns = 'date' , 'a' , 'b' , 'c' to
dd.read_csv()
It reads the data and I perform some operation  which gives me a dask series structure

```
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=1
    float64
        ...
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

How can I fetch the data inside this structure.I know a .compute() function for dask but I dont want to use it as it takes a lot of time..

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no way around to using compute

Comment: So.. is this an excel file or CSV?

Comment: Its a csv ..as written above.It is getting parsed ,I perform operations but returns that series structure.I want to grab that value without compute?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a few values then you might consider the `.head()` method.  This gets the first 10 values by default.